# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting Issue using VALUE

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to conditionally format a range of cells based on the value of the right two digits. I'm using the following formula and it isn't working:

=VALUE(RIGHT($N2,2)) > 80

I'm trying to avoid splitting the column into two separate columns (it's a blood pressure reading, the figures belong together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula evaluates to TRUE and FALSE okay. When you say it isn't working I assume it's not doing anything at all, rather than giving wrong results. Have you remembered to set the format, as well as entering the condition!? Remember it will only format if it evaluates to TRUE... If these are correct, have you entered the formula as the condition and used the '*Use formula to determine which cells to format...Format values where this formula is true*' rule type?

Comment: Yes, I did all of that.  I set it on a cell where VALUE(RIGHT($N2,2)) > 80 is true.  It still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried pasting the formula into a cell, then clicking Evaluate Formula on the Formula tab and keep clicking Evaluate to see what the formula is doing? If that doesn't help, have you tried copying the formula and data to another worksheet or workbook to make sure nothing is being affected by any other settings? It is probably worth changing $N2 to $N$2 for testing purposes. If there is still a problem, try using Undo to remove the new data and formula, then Paste Special > Formulas to paste the formula and Paste Special > Values to paste the data. Any difference?

Comment: Oz, no I hadn't.  But, I will try that now.  Thank you very much.